# Can't hide Spring boot Annotation Processor Message

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am having issues in hiding message in IntelliJ informing me to 
Re-run Spitng Boot Configuration Processor to update generated metadata. Is there way to configure this to resolve message displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Next to the "Open Documentation" link, there is an icon. Click on that and uncheck "Show Spring Boot metadata panel"